# I am getting Unexpected token in App.js file please advise me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i am trying to run with npm start command getting below error in react
Error after trying to run **npm start**

**export default App;**

```
Syntax error: D:/react/react-sidebar-v1/src/App.js: Unexpected token (11:5)

   9 | function App() {
  10 |   return (
  > 11 |     <>
     |      ^
  12 |       <Router>
  13 |         <Navbar />
  14 |         <Switch>
```

**Here is my App.js code**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
Import Reports from './pages/Reports';
import Products from './pages/Products';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
      <Route path='/reports' component={Reports} />
      <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
   </>
  );
  }
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript, it seems like JSX. Are you attempting to run client-side code server-side?

Comment: trying to run client side

Comment: The error you showed clearly is on the server side, so maybe you are trying to bundle the Javascript without having a handler for JSX transpilation configured in your bundler?

Comment: are you sure about the syntax? what is the "Import" expression on importing Reports?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
Import Reports from './pages/Reports'; // should be import instate of Import 
import Products from './pages/Products';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
      <Route path='/reports' component={Reports} />
      <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
   </>
  );
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExYFc.png)